# Memory Game in React

Tags: react.js, jsx

This is my second game in React (I posted a country guessing game 2 days ago). Please review my code.

[Preview](https://davidwico.github.io/react-memory-game/)

Alert: May work only in Google Chrome (I build here)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './MemoryGame.css';

class MemoryGame extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //Array of memory images
    this.ImagePieces = ['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'horse', 'horse',
    'pig', 'pig', 'snake', 'snake', 'fish', 'fish'];
    this.tempCheckArr = [];
    this.state = {
      showImg: Array(this.ImagePieces.length).fill('hidden'),
      divClick: true,
      compareImgArr: [],
      counter: 0
    }   
    this.checkMatch = this.checkMatch.bind(this);
  }

  //Shuffle memory game images
  componentWillMount() {
    function shuffleArray(array) {
      for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
          let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
          [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
      }
      return array;
    }
    shuffleArray(this.ImagePieces);
  }

  //Check for match function
  checkMatch(key, e) {
    //For later hidding images purposes
    this.tempCheckArr.push(key.toString());

    //Create copy of (compareImgArr) and add img src, for later compare
    const imgSrc = e.target.firstChild.src;
    const compareImgArr = [...this.state.compareImgArr];
    compareImgArr.push(imgSrc);

    //Set current clicked item as 'visible' in main array 'showImg'
    const arr = this.state.showImg
    arr[key] = 'visible';

    //Update state, counter for block user click method
    //after unhidding two pieces
    this.setState({
      showImg: arr,
      compareImgArr: compareImgArr,
      counter: this.state.counter + 1
    });

    //Check if 2 items are clicked - if yes - disable clicking
    if (this.state.counter % 2) {
      this.setState({
        divClick: false
      });
      //Check if pictures are matching
      if (compareImgArr[0] === compareImgArr[1]) {
        this.tempCheckArr = [];
        this.setState({
          compareImgArr: [],
          divClick: true
        });
      } else {
        //If pictures not match turn them back to hidden
        var tempArr = this.state.showImg
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        var firstElement = parseInt(this.tempCheckArr[0]);
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        var secondElement = parseInt(this.tempCheckArr[1]);
        setTimeout(()=>{
          tempArr[firstElement] = 'hidden';
          tempArr[secondElement] = 'hidden';
          this.tempCheckArr = [];
          this.setState({
            showImg: tempArr,
            compareImgArr: [],
            divClick: true
          })
        }, 1500)
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Memory Game</h1>
        <div className="mui-panel wrapper">
          {this.ImagePieces.map((text, i) => {
            return (
              <div key={i} className="modal mui-panel" 
                onClick={this.state.divClick ? (e) => this.checkMatch(i, e) : undefined}>
                  <img style={{visibility: this.state.showImg[i]}} src={'./'+text+'.jpg'}
                  srcSet={'./'+text+'_lrg.jpg 1000w'} key={i} alt="Game Element"/>
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default MemoryGame;
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I had quite a few thoughts on this.

## State

Your state seems more complex than it needs to be, and some of it is hiding outside of the `state` variable.
I think all you really need to keep track of are:
 - What order the images are in
 - Which images are currently selected
 - Which images have been guessed correctly

I don't really understand what `tempCheckArr` is, how it's different from `compareImgArr`, or why it's an instance variable.

## Extract stuff

I think you have too much stuff crammed into one component.
I think you need to extract pieces of logic that can be self contained.

#### Prime example: `shuffleArray`

Why is `shuffleArray` declared inside `componentWillMount`?
This is creating a new `shuffleArray` function every time `MemoryGame` is mounted.
I think `shuffleArray` should at least be outside of this component, and really should be in a some sort of `RandomUtil.js` file.

#### Card component

I would also extract out a Card component that renders a card.
It should know:
 - What image to display
 - Whether or not it's selected
 - Whether or not it's been guessed correctly

This way you can keep your MemoryGame component about managing the state of the game while the Card component focuses on presentation.

## Other Thoughts

- Your `<img>` tag doesn't need a `key` prop because it's not the top level thing in an array.
- Why is `ImagePieces` declared on `this`. It seems like it should be part of state.
- (Also why is the `I` in `ImagePieces` uppercase? It seems like this should be `imagePieces`)
- Why are you shuffling ImagePieces in componentWillMount and not just in the constructor?
- It's kinda gross to reach into the DOM to compare the elements `src` attribute, and it makes it harder to understand what you actually want to compare: that the two images selected are of the same thing
- Why are you converting integers to strings when you put them into `tempCheckArr` and converting them back when you take them out? Wouldn't it be easier to just put integers into the array?

## How I would write it

```
const IMAGES = ["cat", "cat", "dog", "dog", "horse", "horse", "pig",
  "pig", "snake", "snake", "fish", "fish"];

class MemoryGame extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // You can simplify your state a lot
    this.state = {
      cards: shuffleArray(IMAGES.slice()),
      selected: [], // indexes which have been selected
      correct: [] // indexes which have been guessed correctly
    };
  }

  // Don't need a componentWillMount

  onCardClick(clickedIndex) {
    const { selected, cards, correct } = this.state;

    if (selected.length === 0) { // selecting a first card
      this.setState({ selected: [clickedIndex] })
    } else if (selected.length === 1) { // they're selecting a second card
      if (cards[selected[0]] === cards[clickedIndex]) {
        // It's a match :)
        // Add selected cards to `correct` and reset selection
        this.setState({
            correct: correct.concat([selected[0], clickedIndex]),
            selected: []
        });
      } else {
        // It's not a match :(
        // Select it for now, and reset selection in a bit
        this.setState({ selected: [selected[0], clickedIndex] });
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({ selected: [] })
        }, 1500);
      }
    }
    // Otherwise they already have 2 selected and we don't wanna do anything
  }

  render() {
    const { correct, selected, cards } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Memory Game</h1>
        <div className="mui-panel wrapper">
          {cards.map((image, i) => (
            <MemoryCard
              key={i}
              image={image}
              isCorrect={correct.includes(i)}
              isSelected={selected.includes(i)}
              onSelect={() => this.onCardClick(i)}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Extracted into it's own component
const MemoryCard = ({ image, isSelected, isCorrect, onSelect }) => (
  <div
    className="modal mui-panel"
    onClick={() => {
      // You can only select a card that's not already correct and
      // isn't currently selected
      if (!isCorrect && !isSelected) {
        onSelect();
      }
    }}
  >
    <img
      style={{ visibility: (isCorrect || isSelected) ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }}
      src={"./" + image + ".jpg"}
      srcSet={"./" + image + "_lrg.jpg 1000w"}
      alt={image}
    />
  </div>
);

// Probably in a different file
function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
  return array;
}

export default MemoryGame;
```